# How could I specify a return type with an umbrella type narrowing in a function declaration in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

How could I specify a return type with an umbrella type narrowing in a function declaration in TypeScript?

E.g. I have the following piece of code (which is taken from [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#improving-template-type-checking-for-custom-directives)):

```
export type T = {};
export type Loaded = { type: 'loaded', data: T };
export type Loading = { type: 'loading' };
export type LoadingState = Loaded | Loading;
export class IfLoadedDirective {
    static ngTemplateGuard_state(dir: IfLoadedDirective, expr: LoadingState): expr is Loaded { return true; };
}
```

Now I want to specify that the return type of the `ngTemplateGuard_state` is boolean. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
export type T = {};
export type Loaded = { type: 'loaded', data: T };
export type Loading = { type: 'loading' };
export type LoadingState = Loaded | Loading;
export class IfLoadedDirective {
    static ngTemplateGuard_state(dir: IfLoadedDirective, expr: LoadingState): expr is Loaded: boolean { return true; };
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

> any
>   'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
>
> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.(1068)

[image]

Also, I was not able to find a documented and explained usage of the umbrella type narrowing. Since, it could probably help me to figure out an answer to my question, I would be thankful if someone would have provided a source to read about it. By the `the umbrella type narrowing` I mean the `expr is Loaded` part in my example.

I need it for educational purposes only. I want to clearly understand such a simple language syntax as the generics constraints and the return type specification.

Comment: This is called type guard in typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: Type guard always returns boolean, no need to explicitly state this

Comment: @AlekseyL., so, just to check with you, please. The following piece of code: `function isA(arg: any): arg is A { return (arg as A).propWhichAShouldHave; }` in a fool proof words means the following: if the result of running the function named `isA` is `true` (or just truthy), then after the `isA` call TypeScript is going to treat the `arg` as of type `A`, otherwise (when the result is false or falsy) TypeScript is going to treat the `arg` as definitely not of type `A`. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) in typescript.

> A type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in some scope. To define a type guard, we simply need to define a function whose return type is a type predicate

In example above `expr is Loaded` is a return type (type predicate) and there's no need (and you can't actually) in providing additional return type (boolean).

> A predicate takes the form `parameterName is Type`, where `parameterName` must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature

Any time `ngTemplateGuard_state` is called with variable `expr` of type `LoadingState`, TypeScript will narrow that variable to type `Loaded` if function returns truthy value.